# Adding Opportunity Products Related List to Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I am trying to build an email template that lists all the OpportunityLineItems in the email body.  Can I use the `<apex: relatedList>` tag?  That is what I am trying to do with the code below, but I am not having any success.  Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and if so, what my issue is?  Thanks in advance.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Opportunity {!relatedTo.Opportunity_Number__c} has been booked and requires Software Fulfillment" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
FICO Software Fulfillment Team,
Opportunity {!relatedTo.Opportunity_Number__c} has been booked and requires Software Fulfillment.

https://fico--dev1.cs30.my.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.Id}

<apex:relatedList list="OpportunityLineItems"/>




</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: by way of reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_intro.htm identifies the VF components that can't be used. As `relatedList` includes buttons (and hence input), they are not permitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use relatedList component inside messaging. It would not really format well anyways since you are using plaintext body. Try using a repeat tag like:

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityLineItems}" var="oli">
      <apex:outputText value="{!oli.PriceboonEntry.Product2.Name}">
      <apex:outputText value="{!oli.UnitPrice}">
      <apex:outputText value="{!oli.Quantity}">
 </apex:repeat>
```

You probably want to change the formatting a bit so it looks better.